# Can I use entered value through ng-model to populate angular ng grid?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-scope, ng-grid

This [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/R1nMDj8mLaXY0wSXKlIR?p=preview) populates a static Html Table correctly based on a search for 'Tim' (Json Data).

```
    var arrItem = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.items, function (item) {
    if(item.fname === enteredValue.firstName || item.lname === enteredValue.lastName
    ||item.address === enteredValue.address && item.phone === enteredValue.phone){
        arrItem.push({
            first: item.fname,
            last: item.lname,
            address: item.address,
            phone: item.phone

        });
```

Now I want to place this data in a NG-Grid.
This [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uf45TcUCkzEs7oMjPROO?p=preview) attempts to load this data into NG Grid based on a Tim Search.  I tried so many ways to do this.  Now I'm trying to assign arrItem to $scope.source and pass that into getPagedDataAsync.  Any ideas?

```
  $scope.source= arrItem;
  $scope.getPagedDataAsync($scope.source, $scope.pagingOptions.pageSize, $scope.pagingOptions.currentPage);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, where you define the gridOptions, you are using the wrong scope variable name.

```
 data: 'myData',
```

should be

```
 data: 'source',
```