# When to use angularJS ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

This [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/R1nMDj8mLaXY0wSXKlIR?p=preview) populates a static Html Table correctly based on a search for 'Tim' (Json Data).

```
    var arrItem = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.items, function (item) {
    if(item.fname === enteredValue.firstName || item.lname === enteredValue.lastName
    ||item.address === enteredValue.address && item.phone === enteredValue.phone){
        arrItem.push({
            first: item.fname,
            last: item.lname,
            address: item.address,
            phone: item.phone

        });
```

Now I want to place this data in a NG-Grid.
This [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uf45TcUCkzEs7oMjPROO?p=preview) attempts to load this data into NG Grid based on a Tim Search.  I tried so many ways to do this.  Should I be using ng-repeat?  Ng-table instead of ng-grid?

```
  $scope.source= arrItem;
  $scope.getPagedDataAsync($scope.source, $scope.pagingOptions.pageSize, $scope.pagingOptions.currentPage);
```

Comment: There's an interesting discussion about here, maybe can help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21375073/best-way-to-represent-a-grid-or-table-in-angularjs-with-bootstrap-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my answer here: [Can I use entered value through ng-model to populate angular ng grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31150593/can-i-use-entered-value-through-ng-model-to-populate-angular-ng-grid/31154567#31154567)